# Coercivity of a bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a very smooth open and bounded set $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$. One can prove that for all $\epsilon >0$, $\exists K_{\epsilon}>0$, such that for all $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ :

$\|u_{/\Gamma}\|^2_{L^2(\Gamma)} \le \epsilon \|u\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)} + K_{\epsilon} \|u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \qquad \qquad (1)$

where $\Gamma$ denotes the boundary of $\Omega$. Now, consider the following family of bilinear forms (in $H^1(\Omega)$) for $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$ :

$b_{\mu,c}(v,w)=\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} \nabla v . \nabla w -\mu \int_{\Gamma} \big( v_{/\Gamma} \big ) \big( w_{/\Gamma} \big ) +c \int_{\Omega} vw$

I would like to show that for all $\mu > 0$, there exists $c_{\mu} >0$ such that $b_{\mu,c_{\mu}}$ be coercive. At first sight, I thought about applying inequation (1) to $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\mu}$, but I end up with $b_{\mu,c_{\mu}}(u,u) \ge C \times \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ instead of $b_{\mu,c_{\mu}}(u,u) \ge C \times \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$.